# Where is strchr in C++?

Tags: c++, c, c++11

I know that `strchr` is in `<string>`.
But the **uva10082** gave the CE:

```
code.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
code.cpp:6:13: warning: unknown escape sequence: '\A'
char x[] = "`1234567890-=QWERTYUIOP[]\ASDFGHJKL;'ZXCVBNM,./";          ^
code.cpp:11:24: error: ‘strchr’ was not declared in this scope
p = strchr(x, char(c));
```

here is my code:(use c++11 to compile)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char x[] = "`1234567890-=QWERTYUIOP[]\ASDFGHJKL;'ZXCVBNM,./";
    int c;
    char* p = NULL;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        p =strchr(x,char(c));
        if (p)
            cout << *(p-1);
        else
            cout << char(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: if you want the character `'\'`, you need to write `"\\"`. It sees "'\A'" as a special character. edit: god SO comment actually interpret the character as well.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strchr

Comment: Check here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
#include <cstring>  // contains strchr
```

also, there's no need to cast the second argument to `char`, because `strchr` takes `int` there

Answer (score 2):

you need to

```
#include<cstring>
```

to have `strchr()`. also, for `getchar()` and `EOF`  you need to

```
#include<cstdio>
```

note that `<string>` library contains for example `std::string` class, while `<cstring>` contains C string functions, like `strchr()`, `strcat()` and so on.

so, your statement that `strchr()` is in `<string>` lib is not true.

Answer (score 1):

I guess `std::strchr` is in `#include <cstring>`